# QtWebKit playing HTML5 video without installing flash player

Tags: qt, html, qtwebkit, qwebview

With latest Flash player installed, and enable the Plugins, my simple example can play youtube videos

OS: windows 7

Qt: 4.7.4 (both 32 & 64bit works)

However, according to "http://www.youtube.com/html5", my example browser supports "Video tag" and "H.264", I was wondering why can't I just DISABLE the Plugins and play the video as usual? I have followed the procedure of " Watch a Video in YouTube's HTML5 Player" 
http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/watch-video-in-youtubes-html5-player.html

but not work at all~

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  //QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);

  QWebView *view = new QWebView();
  view->load(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTl3U6aSd2w&html5=True"));
  view->show();
  return a.exec();
 }
```

Is there any code missing or I should enable anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the version you are using doesn't have html5 video support.

From the QtWebKit page:

> Web Developer Features
>
> These are some of the new features present in QtWebKit-2.2:
>
> **Support for HTML5 media (audio/video)**

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitFeatures22#WebDeveloperFeatures

QtWebKit 2.2 is included in Qt-4.8.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. However, the QtWebKit 2.2 included in Qt-4.8 does not have video and audio support; it seems like a bug.        http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/11865

Comment: It seems the bug refers to QT 4.8 RC1. Have you tried using the release version of QT 4.8?

Comment: I installed "Qt libraries 4.8.0 for Windows (VS 2010, 275 MB)" and launched their fancyBrowser demo. The http://html5test.com/ shows 0 score for both video and audio support. Youtube asked me to install flash plugin. Still no luck~    Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a blog post about how I've solved this issue for our project.  It involves building Qt + qt-mobility, and also a bug fix in qt-mobility.  See http://blog.enthought.com/open-source/fun-with-qtwebkit-html5-video/

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like that

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Comment: I've tried this with no success, and seen this response in other forums. Does anybody tried this with success?