# QWebView not playing HTML5 video

Tags: qt, qt4, html5-video

I have Windows 7 Ultimate x86 and Qt 4.8.1.
But I can't play html5 video in QWebView widget. So how can I do this?

Comment: You may need a newer build of QtWebKit that supports HTML5 video. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650119/qtwebkit-playing-html5-video-without-installing-flash-player